# What Vue does when input field's value does not match with binded "data"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know about `v-model`, but first I need to clarify `v-bind` behaviour.

Consider below example:

```html
<div id="app">
  <input 
    type="text" 
    :value="inputtedValue"
    @input="() => { onInput() }"
  >
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      inputtedValue: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput() {
      console.log(this.inputtedValue);
    }
  }
};
```

[Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-merkle-o0nbb?file=/src/App.vue:163-334)

Is my hypothesis about this example right?

1. `:value="inputtedValue"` **does not mean** "`:value` attribute value (tautology?) is fully depends on `inputtedValue`"; it could differ.
2. Rather it means "When `inputtedValue` updated, `:value` attribute value will be updated", but if to type new value to input field, Vue **will not know** about it.

But most interesting experimental data is:

3. If `inputtedValue` has not been changed, we **can not change** the `value` attribute value even it does not match with `inputtedValue`.

Suppose we want to remove minus signs from input:

```html
<div id="app">
  <input 
    type="text" 
    :value="inputtedValue"
    @input="$event => { onInput($event.target.value) }"
  >
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      inputtedValue: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(rawValue) {
      
     if (rawValue.includes("-")) {
       this.inputtedValue = rawValue.replace("-", "");
     } else {
       this.inputtedValue = rawValue;
     }

     console.log(this.inputtedValue);
    }
  }
};
```

[Fillde](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-lehmann-wcb91?file=/src/App.vue:186-521)

If to input minus, `this.inputtedValue = rawValue.replace("-", "");` will not change the existing `this.inputtedValue`. So we have `this.inputtedValue` and `value` attribute's value discrepancy again:

[image]

### What I want instead?

1. User inputs the symbol
2. If symbol is valid - add it to `input` element and emit `input` event (for components)
3. If symbols is invalid - do not add it to `input` element and don't not emit `input` event (for components)

`v-model` behavior is differ:

1. User inputs the symbol
2. binded variable value changes

Now we consider inputted value as invalid, we can change the binded value and vue will change the input's value. Too much movements, and also, we can't compare new value and previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent unwanted characters appearing in your text box, even if typed, you really need to use a `@keydown` handler. You can also use a computed property with *getter* and *setter* to control the data-flow while using `v-model`

```html
<input type="text" v-model="editableValue" @keydown="checkSymbol">
```

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({ inputtedValue: "" }),
  computed: {
    editableValue: {
      get: vm => vm.inputtedValue,
      set (rawValue) {
        this.inputtedValue = rawValue
        this.$emit("input", this.inputtedValue)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkSymbol($event) {
      if ($event.key === "-") {
        $event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Edit youthful-fog-5bmin]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "You're missing a vital ingredient from your examples": Sorry I did not understand this part. What I missed? I binded the `value`, have I? "you need to capture it from the $event"- I did it in the second example. Or `@input="$event => { onInput($event.target.value) }"` is wrong? In first example, we don' capture the input yet.

Comment: I added the template part of second example.

Comment: Right, I've removed that part from my answer now

Comment: Please tell me does `keyup` ALWAYS firing before `input`?

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD I've updated the CodeSandbox demo with some more logging. The event ordering goes `keydown`, `input`, `keyup`. If `keydown` prevents the default action, `input` does not fire at all

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD Not a problem at all 